# curl - Issue with special character URL running inside shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl

when running curl command on the command line, putting quotes around url with '&' works, but when running inside a shell script, its not working as expected.

```
      curl -Lks -o /dev/null -w  "%{url_effective}\n"  "https://www.XXXX.com?ver=test1&ver1=test2"
```

Comment: Can you update the question with what you expected to happen, and what actually happened?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you're using a different shell to interactively run that command then you specify as the shell that should execute the file.

Try executing

```
echo $SHELL
```

If you want to have the same semantics, that same shell must be used as the so-called [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) executor.

Comment: echo $SHELL shows "/bin/bash", and also in my shell script on top i have mentioned  "#!/bin/bash", So i might be using the same shell!